# Adding CSM Content Image not visible on Portal in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, portal, salesforce-communities

Images are not visible on the page, any idea why are they not showing.
i created workspace and content and added it to the channel and the content is available there and published but it's not visible.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfbbd.jpg)

Gave all possible permissions i guess